# How would I call a scene by pressing a button on swift playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

how would I make this button open the GameScene1 when clicked?
This is my code so far.

```
class GameScene1: SKScene{
    override func didMove(to view: SKView){
    }
}
let scene1 = GameScene1(size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 640))
scene1.scaleMode = .aspectFill
scene1.backgroundColor = .blue

let view2 = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: scene1.size.width, height: scene1.size.height
view2.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view2



class Receiver{
    @objc func buttonClicked(){
    }
}
let view1 = UIView()
let receiver = Receiver()
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:100, height:50))
button.setTitle("start", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(receiver, action: #selector(Receiver.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(button)
```

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't have a lot of experience with SKScene's, but this is what I would do. You really only need one SKView in your playground, which you could store as a `static let` inside a file with game variables. You could then create different scenes, for instance one for the menu, one for the first level, second level etc.

The following code creates a button and gives it an action. The action creates a constant called scene, which is the scene you want to move to next. Then you just call `presentScene()` with the scene, and a SKTransition, like the one below, which is simply a 2.5 second sliding animation from the right.

ButtonNode class, which is simply a node that acts as a button, which you can add to your scene.

```
class ButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {

    var action: ((ButtonNode) -> Void)?

    var isSelected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            alpha = isSelected ? 0.8 : 1
        }
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    init(texture: SKTexture, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.white, size: size)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
        action?(self)
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        action?(self)
    }
}
```

Creating the button and giving it the action to move to a next scene. This can be done in any SKScene class.

```
startButton = ButtonNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "start-button"), size: CGSize(width: 184, height: 72))
        startButton.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        startButton.action = { (button) in
            if let scene = IntroCutScene(fileNamed: "IntroCutScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                self.scene!.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                GameVariables.sceneView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.moveIn(with: SKTransitionDirection.right, duration: 2.5))
            }
        }
        self.addChild(startButton)
```